# Is differentiability defined at an isolated point of the function's domain?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Say we have the function $f:(0,1)\cup\{2\}\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=5$.

Is $f$ differentiable or not differentiable (or neither) at $2$?

Is $f$ a differentiable function?

Comment: Differentiabilty at an isolated point is not defined.

Comment: No. One can only take a limit over such $h\to0$ that $f(a+h)$ is defined. Since for an isolated point all such small enough $h$ must be zero the difference quotients $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ are not defined for small $h$, and neither is the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiability is defined in terms of *sequences of differences* $h_1,h_2,h_3\dots$ that are *all nonzero* and yet *converge to zero*. Such a sequence does not exist in the given domain, as there does not exist a number $k$ in the domain where $|2-k|=0.2$ or $0.1$ or indeed any number smaller than $1$. Hence differentiability is not defined at isolated points.

Comment: Is $f$ a differentiable function?

Comment: @iqntt1s Over $(0,1)$, yes. At $\{2\}$, no.